# Relational algebra syntax

Tags: sql, syntax, relational-algebra

First time i encounter a relational algebra for databases question today, and i can't seem to find the answer.

I have 3 tables, Batch, Channel and Market.

Batch is connected to Channel and Market by foregein keys (channelID, marketID).

What is the correct notation for a query of this sort:

```
select * from batch, channel, market 
where batch.channelID=channel.channelID AND batch.marketID=market.marketID
```

Thanks

---

If i understood correctly, i need to write as follows:

```
π...(Batch⋈                                   Channel⋈                                Market
           (batch.channelID=channel.channelID)        (batch.marketID=market.marketID)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be *batch ⋈ channel ⋈ market* (natural joins are associative and commutative).

**EDIT**: since the attribute names are the same for each join (you're comparing `batch.channelID` with `channel.channelID`), you're in a situation where the query can be written with natural joins, and there's no need to write (xxx = yyy) beneath the ⋈ operator when it's representing a natural join.

You *could* write it as θ-joins instead, in which case your syntax would be almost correct, but I feel that using θ-joins to represent natural joins kind of misses the point. The change you need to do is that, since θ-joins are not associative, you need to add brackets : *(batch ⋈ channel) ⋈ market*

Comment: Hi, not sure i understood. Is my update correct as to how i should write the sub-notation of the join fields? (I'm required to describe the full query).